# bash argument containing R column info, from character to numeric

Tags: r, bash

Trying to pass column coordinates from bash to an R script. For example:

```
Rscript script.R Input.table "29:37,40:48" "11:19" Output.file
```

I then have the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

a <- read.table(args[1], header=T, row.names=1)

locg1 <- c(args[2])
locg2 <- c(args[3])
meangroup1 <- mean(a[,locg1])
meangroup2 <- mean(a[,locg2])
```

However when I run the script I get execution halted with "undefined columns selected" as an error.

I believe it's because the bash arguments are all interpreted as character and I am not sure how to convert a character like "29:37,40:48" into an actual numerical list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert in using `Rscript` from the command line to call R scripts, but given this simplified version:

```
Rscript script.R "29:37,40:48"
```

we can try using `strsplit` to separate the two times:

```
times <- strsplit(args[1], ",")[[1]]
locg1 <- times[1]
locg2 <- times[2]
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that it's necessary to add [[1]] such as times <- strsplit(args[1], ",")[[1]], otherwise it doesn't work to use times[1].

Comment: @AdrianP. Sorry, in fact I was doing that in a demo, but it never got copied over.